# Select TOP 3 values with their respective groups and values

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pivot

So i have a table like this

| user | GROUP | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | G1 | 0.9 |
| A | G2 | 0.8 |
| A | G3 | 0.3 |
| A | G4 | 0.7 |
| B | G1 | 0.9 |
| B | G2 | 0.8 |
| B | G3 | 0.7 |
| C | G1 | 0.9 |
| C | G2 | 0.8 |

and need to get to something like this

| user | first_G | Fir_G_val | second_G | sec_G_val | third_G | thi_G_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | G1 | 0.9 | G2 | 0.8 | G4 | 0.7 |
| B | G1 | 0.9 | G2 | 0.8 | G3 | 0.7 |
| C | G1 | 0.9 | G2 | 0.8 | NULL | NULL |

I tried in different ways, none worked out for me (Guided by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647674/bigquery-select-top-3-with-group-by-condition))

Comment: tried with this guide too
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#:~:text=NTH_VALUE,-NTH_VALUE%20(value_expression%2C%20constant_integer_expression&text=Returns%20the%20value%20of%20value_expression,unless%20IGNORE%20NULLS%20is%20present.

Answer (score 0):

This operation is called pivot and can be carried out by:

- selecting the ranking for each group, using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function
- extracting group and value alternatively, for each of the new field
- aggregating values on each user

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_ ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT user_, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN GROUP_ END) AS first_G,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN VALUE_ END) AS first_G_val,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN GROUP_ END) AS second_G,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN VALUE_ END) AS second_G_val,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN GROUP_ END) AS third_G,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN VALUE_ END) AS third_G_val
FROM cte
GROUP BY user_
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, i repeats the same GROUP_ but with different VALUE_ (but ordered correctly)

Comment: Changed the ordering in the row_number function, check if now it works correctly.

Comment: It was a problem with my origin-table! thank you so much!!